# html2canvas - no screenshot for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, webpage-screenshot, html2canvas

I have a task where i need to load a URL `(e.g www.yahoo.com)` , on my webpage, and take screenshot. I am using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) for screenshot and appending it to the body of the page.

The page specified by the URL is successfully loaded in an iframe inside a div element. But when i try to take screenshot of that, the iframe area comes blank.

Below is the code for `previewURL` and `screenshot`.

```
//to preview the URL content
function previewUrl(url,target){
    //use timeout coz mousehover fires several times
    clearTimeout(window.ht);
    window.ht = setTimeout(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById(target);
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />';
    },20);      
}

function pic() {
      html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
         }
     });
 };
```

And the HTML part goes here :

```
<body>
    <input type="button" class="clear-button" onclick="pic();" value="Take Screenshot" >
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onmouseover="previewUrl(this.href,'div1')">Hover to load</a>
    <div id="div1"></div>

</body>
```

The screenshot looks something like this :
[image]

I am stuck and don't understand why is this happening. I want something similar to [this](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) which can load URL and then onclick can give me screenshot.

Comment: as canvas is subject to same origin policy, you have to proxify it server side, just like your posted link works

Comment: How do we achieve that? An example or something would be beneficial.

Comment: You can't do that with html2canvas. It says so in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you are not pointing correctly to the part of the `iframe` that you want to take the screenshot, instead you are pointing directly to the document body.

you can try this:

```
var body = $(iframe).contents().find('body')[0];
        html2canvas(body, {
            onrendered: function( canvas ) {
                $("#content").empty().append(canvas);
            },
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI, I don't think this works if the iframe is not from the same domain, due to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).  I also wasn't even able to get this to work with the same origin, on my local file system.  Maybe this would work with a proper domain.

Comment: I just tried this with Chrome and my local IIS and I'm unable to even get IFrame contents on my local test domain, or via the file system reference.  `$(iframe).contents().text()` just returns an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it's not possible:

> The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java applets. It doesn't render iframe content either.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations

Comment: I think this is because this would be a major security issue.  Imagine if you're able to iframe and then screenshot a user's bank's website.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked 4 me:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    html2canvas($('#'+idd2).contents().find('body')[0], {
        allowTaint : true,
        logging: true,
        profile: true,
        useCORS: true
        }).then(function(canvas) {
        document.getElementById('screen').appendChild(canvas);     
    }); }, 3000);
```

Comment: I can't see how that could work. `$('#'+idd2).contents().find('body')[0]` looks like it is trying to read the iframe, which is going to error because the iframe in the question is **cross-origin**.